# How does the java-service-wrapper decide whether to use the 32 or 64 bit VM?

Tags: java, linux, java-service-wrapper

We're using a vendor licensed copy of the [Tanuki Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp) to start their platform. It ships with wrappers for every O/S flavour and architecture and the recommended profile is a 64 bit VM with a 3 gig heap.

We're using 64 bit Redhat, but I've been unable to find a wrapper configuration option which forces the `wrapper.sh` script to use the `wrapper-linux-x86-64` binary. The only way I have been able to get the wrapper to start in 64 bit mode is by deleting the `wrapper-linux-x86-32` binary.

Is there a way to force the wrapper into 64 bit mode? Is it simply trying to choose the fastest appropriate VM setting and choosing 32 bit mode when it can because our heap is less than 4 gig?

I'd like to learn more about how the java-service-wrapper makes the 32/64 bit decision but have been unable to find anything online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what version of the wrapper are you running?

in 3.4.0 this has been improved:
Changed the scripts and batch files to try to load the wrapper executable according to the system, i.e. on 64-bit systems the 64bit binary of the wrapper is attempted to be executed first and after this fails the 32 bit gets attempted to be loaded. This behaviour is primaly useful with the delta-pack of the wrapper.

cheers,
christian

Comment: if you can't upgrade to 3.4.0 for some reason you could also make a quick diff on the src/bin/sh.script.in and apply the changes.

Comment: sorry, hit "add comment" to fast. the parts in "# Resolve the os", "# Resolve the architecture" and "# Decide on the wrapper binary to use." should get applied. cheers